# Using f distribution in python with anaconda

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I have very strange issue in my anaconda - spyder.

For some purpose,  I want to use f distribution fit. So I imported and tried f distribution via scipy as this

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import f

a = f.rvs(29, 18, size = 1000) #29 and 18 params are used in official site
f.fit(a)
```

and I recieved following error:

```
C:\Users\rpaca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:2303: 
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
Lhat = muhat - Shat*mu
```

It looks very much as package problem. Is there a way how to solve it?

Comment: This is not an error. It's simply a warning. The results will still generate. If you go to the example using the `beta` distribution in their [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html), it will return a warning as well.

Comment: ok, but why is this warning generated?

Comment: The warning is generated from the optimization process where an invalid value was encountered while calculating Lhat. What you should take note is that the solution may not be the globally optimal solution, as noted in the docs.

Comment: ok, I copy. Is there any way how to aviod this warning?

Comment: You could try and define starting values for `loc` and `scale`, fixing them, or suppressing the warnings with `np.seterr('ignore')`.